# login user by loginwindow by application in mac

Tags: macos, authentication

I have written a program that pops up in front of the loginwindow app and asks for certain information. Once the information is validated. The loginwindow can be seen and u can select which user to log in. 
I want to run script/bash code or something within my app so that the user does not get the chance to see the loginwindow. Instead, the application should login the guest user itself. I tried using applescript i.e

```
set logInUser to "Guest"
set logInPassword to "Guest"

tell application "System Events"

    tell application process "loginwindow"

        key code 53

        delay 1

        key code 125
        delay 1
        key code 36 using option down
        delay 1
        keystroke tab
        delay 1
        key code 117
        delay 0.5
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.5
        key code 117
        keystroke return
        delay 1
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        repeat with aChar in characters of logInUser
            keystroke aChar
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.5
        repeat with aChar in characters of logInPassword
            keystroke aChar
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        key code 98 using control down
        delay 0.2
        keystroke return

    end tell
end tell
```

Since loginwindow is not responding to this applescript, i tried bash too but nothing is work. Any help would be great. :(

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know what you're really trying to do here. The supported way to inject synchronous events during login is with an [authentication hook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2228/_index.html). This is much more powerful than trying to "run in front of LoginWindow." The problem with interrupting `loginwindow` is that you need to deal with the cases of logout and fast-user-switch. You can also use loginwindow's [LoginHook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html) to run a script before login is completed. But again, these are all after the user has entered their credentials (in the case of `LoginHook`, it's after the credentials have been validated).

That said, the best place to put something before LoginWindow is to create an old-style `SystemStarter` daemon in `/Library/StartupItems`. These are run synchronously before `loginwindow`, but just during initial startup (not after logout or during FUS).

Comment: i block the user completely...dont worry about that... and i cant use a loginhook cause that too runs AFTER the user has logged in.i have 3 account A,B,C and a and b are admin. C is a guest account which is flushed off once the user logs off.when my app launches, it asks for token number which is fetched from my website. when validated. 
I DONT want to show loginwindow.instead, i want to login the C account through my application.whther by applescript OR bash or whatever.i hope now u understand the question.
login the Guest user through my app without loginwindow popping up

Comment: Why not login the guest user automatically, and use the authentication hook mentioned above to hang the login and fetch the token before allowing it to finish. That will bypass login window. Admin users can use fast-user switching to switch away from the guest account.

Comment: you mean autologin rite!!! no that does not work for me since it somehow crashes my application. Also i want to run the script from within the application so that i could for 1 case put Guest user and for the other 2nd case just show the loginwindow...i havent looked up authentication hook .. will see n update ...Loginhook cant work since it works AFTER a user has logged in so its out of question..thanks for ur reply Rob